# Voting corrected and user deleted, 10k+ rep points

Tags: discussion, sock-puppets, voting-correction

I just recently looked at a profile of a user and found some hard spikes downwards in the graph.

So I looked at the reputation points and found that it’s more than 10k he/she has lost due to voting corrections and users being deleted during the time this user has been a member.

That users get deleted is nothing you can do something about; it happens. But if one user is about 2k points, it sets some alarms (at least in me). Has this user gone under the radar with multiple [sock puppet accounts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sock_puppet_account), and only some of them been removed?

For those with almighty powers, I flagged three of this users' comments today.

Comment: If you flagged the questions already, what exactly are you expecting to come out of this question?

Comment: @ivarni I have not flagged the questions. I have flagged the users comments begging the OP to accept his/her answer. How am I supposed to flag an answer that this user has posted and some user has upvoted that is now deleted. Your question/statement does not make sense.

Comment: Flag one of their posts, select "in need of moderator intervention" and explain the situation.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry that I had some freudian slippers and confused *"comments"* and *"questions"*. If you've already contacted the mods via flagging, what are the purpose of contacting the community via asking a question? We can't do much about this, we don't even know what the account is/was.

Comment: @ivarni My experience so far with flagging for mods is more or less like flipping a coin. I posted it in the hope that "more coins in the air has a better success rate".

Comment: Flagging comments is an extremely poor and insufficient way to make moderators aware of anything except the single action the an do with the comment, which is delete (or keep if they disagree with the flag). Use a custom mod flag on a post to explain any fishy behavior and/or trends, and link to evidence or mention that you already flagged multiple similar cases. My experience is that my moderator flags are all handled as I intended with less then 60 declined flags with over 11,000 flags raised. That is by far the outcome you get with flipping a coin.

Comment: @rene sigh... My intention with the flagging was NOT to get the attention of the mods. I flagged **first** then was curious why this individual with 100k+ are so adamant to get rep point that he/she does not understand that three comments deleted with begging is a sign. At that point I found the strange voting corrections and posted this. What I had in mind with the coin flip is that I have at least two flags that was declined but later got handled just as I flagged them.

Comment: *Just as I flagged them*. I bet those comments had the word *accept* in them, as in *Please accept my answer* or variations of that. There are phrases that allow for a single flag to be enough to nuke a comment. No mod will ever see those flags.

Comment: Correct, I know. Hence the post here.

Comment: related at MSE: [Wiping votes on deletion of highly active accounts (-865 points on “User was removed”)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173045/165773)

Answer (score 34):

If you can see reputation changes due to votes being invalidated, or users being removed, it's safe to say that they have not flown under the radar. Aside from the most blatant serial voting, vote invalidation is a manual process, as is account deletion. That means that a moderator or employee was involved, and it's safe to say that warnings / suspensions most likely accompanied these events.

The user you had flagged had this questionable voting taken care of years ago, and I see little evidence of current ongoing vote manipulation.

I'll note that it took me a while to figure out who you were talking about, even looking at your flag history, since you only flagged their comments with the standard "no longer needed". As rene points out above, comment flags focus our attention on the commenting behavior of someone, not anything else, and there's no way we could have known that you wanted us to investigate their voting history from these.

If you have concerns about anomalous voting that you believe hasn't been caught, please use a custom flag on a post, not a comment, and we'll review it. We accept almost all of these, as long as there was something publicly visible that doesn't look right.

Answer (score 29):

If they lost large amounts of reputation due to user deletions, then you can pretty much guarantee that a moderator was involved there. Users with that many votes to a single other user require staff approval before the deletion is finalized in case we need to transfer votes to the Community user when they self-delete, and we would've investigated any connections there. In any other cause, the user would have been deleted directly by the moderator. So somebody was aware of any unsavory behavior at the time of deletion and would've taken any appropriate action around it.

Voting corrections, on the other hand, can be either automated or manual. Automated ones generally pick up very obvious attempts, and nobody is notified of them nor do they really need to be. If we wanted to know when automatic reversals took place, we could easily make a feature that lists when they took place. But it's not extremely useful information to have. Manual corrections are carried out by staff and so someone would have been involved in the situation.

Bottom line here is that you can trust any behavior regarding their voting in the past has already been handled and that there is nothing further that you need to do. Flagging it is not necessary.

Comment: Already downvoting and many things cost reputation. Why deduct for user deletion? Cutting reps for user deletion actually underestimate answerer's effort.
\n\nPlease pardon me if I said anything wrong

Comment: @Toaster this is probably to prevent abuse. Otherwise I could for example create second / sock-puppet account, cast a bunch of quick upvotes on posts from my "primary" account and after that, quickly delete sock puppet, leaving myself with bunch of rep points "out of thin air" and no trace to find out about the fraud

Comment: @gnat Good but scary logic...

Comment: this is why we can't have nice things

Comment: I got to know about automated correction from here so I though I should share my experience.

My reputation had gone through "voting correction" where almost 280 reputation was deleted and I was shocked that is it a glich or anything else. So after that I visited Meta and got to know about "voting correction". The reason was "serial voting", and due to which automated correction was done.